# Selecting different types of nodes or NULL values with XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath

Providing we have the following xml structure:

```
<root>
   <nodeA>
     <nodeB>Some text</nodeB>
   </nodeA>
   <nodeA>Some text</nodeA>
   <nodeA>
     <nodeB>Some other text</nodeB>
   </nodeA>
   ...
</root>
```

Is there a way to select "nodeB" nodes or NULL value instead for each nodeA, so for the example above it returns:

```
nodeB
NULL
nodeB
```

The order of elements is important.

Thank you!

Comment: And any way in XPath version greater 1.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XPath 2.0 you can use `for` loop and `if` statement like so :

```
for $a in //nodeA 
return 
    if($a/nodeB) then $a/nodeB 
    else 'NULL'
```

Tested online [here](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi), and given input XML as posted in question the output is as wanted :

```
Some text
NULL
Some other text
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution! I found this lib: https://xpath2.codeplex.com/
but not sure we can use it to query DOM elements in IE.